# Syntax Error or access violation - SQL query & Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my query, i am trying to compare today's date only (without time) to my field `created_at` but i get the error below

> > SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2018-08-29 DATE(created_at)' at line 1

**Controller**

```
$item_shipped =  Item::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->whereRaw('DATE(created_at)' , '=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())->get();

        return $item_shipped;
```

How do i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions) doesn't accept the operator parameter. You have to write the whole condition and it takes the second parameter which is an array of bindings.

You need this:

```
->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?', [Carbon::now()->toDateString()])->get();
```